# MySQL query to find duplicate Users

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has 2 columns (ip_address and customer_id). I am trying to find a way within MySQL to find people who have logged in with multiple accounts but the same IP.

For example if customer_id 3 and customer_id 7 have both logged in on 1.1.1.1 I want to be able to find this.

I don't need to know if it is the same user on the same IP (or the same user on different IPs), just if it is different users on the same IP.

Comment: How are your tables defined? What query did you try and failed?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   "myTable" as "a" join "myTable" as "b" on ("a"."ip_address" = "b."ip_address")
WHERE  "a"."customer_id" <> "b"."customer_id";
```

This is first creating a list of all permutation of entries with same ip (even same line in fact) and filtering it for those lines having same ip but different customer_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try next query

```
SELECT a.customer_id AS aid, a.ip_address AS ip, b.customer_id  AS bid
FROM log AS a, log AS b 
WHERE a.ip_address = b.ip_addres AND a.customer_id <> b.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see it now lists all of the IPs and the customer ids. Is there a way in mySQL to group them together so it says IP ADDRESS - USER1, USER2 , IP ADDRESS2 , USER 1, USER 7

Comment: May be like this
SELECT ip, aid, bid FROM (SELECT a.customer_id AS aid, a.ip_address AS ip, b.customer_id  AS bid FROM log AS a, log AS b  WHERE a.ip_address =b.ip_address AND a.customer_id <> b.customer_id GROUP BY aid, bid) AS t GROUP BY ip;

Answer (score 0):

You can group the ip_address and find how many customers have same ip.

```
select a.ip_address
       ,group_concat(a.customer_id) as customers
       ,count(distinct a.customer_id) as customers_count 
       from  database.table a 
group by a.ip_address
having customers_count > 1
```